# My lex pattern doesn't work to match my input file, how to correct it?

Tags: parsing, printing, match, lex

I've got a simple pattern to match: head+content+tail, I've got a lex file like below:

```
$ cat b.l
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
%%
"12" {printf("head\n");}
"34" {printf("tail\n");}
.* {printf("content\n");}
%%
```

I hope when meeting "12" it will print "head", when meet "34" it will print "tail", any other contiguous string, it will print "content".

So I compile and run it:

```
lex b.l && gcc lex.yy.c -ll
$ echo '12sdaesre34'|a.out
content
```

My expectation is, it will print

```
head
content
tail
```

But actually it prints only "content" line. Did I get anything wrong, how to correct it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(F)lex always matches the longest possible token. Since `.*` will match any sequence which doesn't contain a newline character, it will happily match `12sdaesre34`. (In (f)lex, `.` matches any character other than newline.) Thus the `34` is no longer available to be matched.

To fix it, you have to be clear about what you want `content` to match. For example, the following will match anything which doesn't contain a digit:

```
[^[:digit:]]+   { printf("content\n"); }
```

You might want to add newline to the list of characters to not match:

```
[^\n[:digit:]]+   { printf("content\n"); }
```

Or perhaps you want to match the longest sequence not containing `34`. That's trickier but it can be done:

```
([^3]|3+[^34])+   { printf("content\n"); }
```

However, that will still match initial `12`, so it won't be enough to solve the problem.

If your input always consists of strings of the form `12...34` possibly interspersed with other content, you can match the entire `12...34` sequence and split it into three tokens. That's undoubtedly the simplest solution, since the beginning and end markers are of a known length. The first of the following patterns matches a string which doesn't start `12`, ending just before the first instance of `12`, and the second one matches a string starting `12` and ending at the first instance of `34` (which is matched). Neither of the patterns will match an input which contains an unmatched `12`; so a third rule is added to match that case; it looks a lot like the second rule but doesn't include the match for `34` at the end. Because (f)lex always matches the longest possible token, the third rule will only succeed if the second rule fails.

```
([^1]|1+[^12])*         { puts("content"); }
12([^3]|3+[^34])*34     { puts("head content tail"); }
12([^3]|3+[^34])*       { puts("error"); }
```

Normally, you would want to actually capture the value of `content` to pass on to the calling program. In the first rule, that is just `yytext`, but in the second rule the content consists of `yyleng-4` characters starting at `yytext+2` (in order to remove the leading and trailing delimiters).

For most purposes, it is necessary to copy the matched token if you need to keep it, because `yytext` points into an internal data structure used by the lexical scanner and the pointer will be invalidated by the next pattern match. In the case of the first rule, you could create a copy of the string using `strcpy`, but for the second rule, you'd want to make the copy yourself:

```
([^1]|1+[^12])*         { yylval = strcpy(yytext); ... }
12([^3]|3+[^34])*34     { yylval = malloc(yyleng-3);
                          memcpy(yylval, yytext, yyleng-4);
                          yylval[yyleng-4] = '\0';
                          ...
                        }
```

Those assume that `yylval` is a global variable of type `char*`, and that somewhere in the code you `free()` the string saved by the rule. They also assume that you do something with `yylval` in the omitted code (`...`), or that you return to the caller with an indication as to whether the head and tail were encountered.

Comment: Thanks but still the answer is not so correct, I tried the rule of 

    ([^3]|3+[^34])+   { printf("content\n"); }

Now the result is still not I wated:

 $ echo 12dsfadsf34|a.out
 content
 tail
 content

Comment: @HindForsum: Yes, you're quite right. I added some suggestions as to how you might proceed, but obviously it is just a rough outline because I really don't know your requirements. I'm generally assuming that you have some familiarity with string processing in C.